# Unity game (x64) seems to crash after ~12 minutes of play

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I've just started working with Unity, and I have made a game with the new 2D features. The game works perfectly fine in the editor, consistent frame rate, no errors, etc. However, when I build a Windows .exe the game seems to crash after playing for a certain period of time ranging from 7-15 minutes.

There is no performance drop leading up to the crash and looking at my RAM and CPU usage nothing seems out of the ordinary. It simply closes and says game.exe has stopped working.

I can't seem to find any pattern or correlation before it crashes. I've built the game in developer mode and looked at the output log for the game, but nothing seems out of the ordinary for that either. I have tried the game on two 64 bit Windows 8.1 computers and one 64 bit Windows 8 computer all producing the same results. I always build the game in 64 bit.

If anyone has any inkling of what may be causing this please let me know.

Here is the unity output log produced for the game if anyone is interested:

```
Initialize engine version: 4.3.2f1 (0517a5ae8669)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 9.0c [aticfx64.dll 8.17.10.1230]
    Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6900 Series
    Vendor:   ATI
    VRAM:     2035 MB (via DXGI)
    Caps:     Shader=30 DepthRT=1 NativeDepth=1 NativeShadow=1 DF16=1 INTZ=1 RAWZ=0 NULL=1 RESZ=1 SlowINTZ=1
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\GSS2\GSS2_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\GSS2\GSS2_Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\GSS2\GSS2_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\GSS2\GSS2_Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
- Completed reload, in  0.043 seconds
desktop: 1920x1080 60Hz; virtual: 1920x1080 at 0,0
 Initializing input.

 Input initialized.

UnloadTime: 0.551156 ms
Unloading 4 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)

Unloading 31 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 252.
Total: 1.053136 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.018866 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.014227 ms MarkObjects: 0.135160 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.098045 ms)

Platform assembly: C:\Users\Saif\Desktop\GSS2\GSS2_Data\Managed\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
UnloadTime: 0.450946 ms
Unloading 1 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)

Unloading 41 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 237.
Total: 0.930657 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.019176 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.014227 ms MarkObjects: 0.138562 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.065260 ms)

UnloadTime: 0.506618 ms
Unloading 2 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0 / Dirty serialized files: 0)

Unloading 30 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 1233.
Total: 1.309538 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.063095 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.027217 ms MarkObjects: 0.386614 ms  DeleteObjects: 0.111035 ms)

HandleD3DDeviceLost
  HandleD3DDeviceLost: needs reset, doing it
FullResetD3DDevice
ResetD3DDevice
dev->Reset
D3Dwindow device not lost anymore
HandleD3DDeviceLost
  HandleD3DDeviceLost: needs reset, doing it
FullResetD3DDevice
ResetD3DDevice
dev->Reset
D3Dwindow device not lost anymore
HandleD3DDeviceLost
  HandleD3DDeviceLost: needs reset, doing it
FullResetD3DDevice
ResetD3DDevice
dev->Reset
D3Dwindow device not lost anymore
HandleD3DDeviceLost
  HandleD3DDeviceLost: needs reset, doing it
FullResetD3DDevice
ResetD3DDevice
dev->Reset
D3Dwindow device not lost anymore
HandleD3DDeviceLost
  HandleD3DDeviceLost: needs reset, doing it
FullResetD3DDevice
ResetD3DDevice
dev->Reset
D3Dwindow device not lost anymore
</pre>

This is how my windows event logs look after the game crashes:
<pre>
Fault bucket 85906700254, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: GSS2.exe
P2: 4.3.2.30490
P3: 52a8d945
P4: GSS2.exe
P5: 4.3.2.30490
P6: 52a8d945
P7: c0000005
P8: 00000000003fa184
P9:
P10:

Attached files:
C:\Users\Saif\AppData\Local\Temp\WER8766.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml

These files may be available here:
C:\Users\Saif\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_GSS2.exe_9199f253cfc16a3bf93fe45323550645140d78c_7b5fff4e_004fb1e1

Analysis symbol:
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 0f55d21e-9cf5-11e3-bf0d-f46d0412ebde
Report Status: 0
Hashed bucket: 2f21de34ebe1ea1257d119fc4445222c
```

I built the game in 32 bit (x86), and it seems to have fixed the problem. It does not crash at all, however 64 bit still crashes. Why may this be the case?

Comment: What is the exception when the game crashes?  If you can't view it at the time of the crash, you should be able to see it within control panel --> view event logs --> windows events --> applications

Comment: Have you tried to look at the profiler?

Comment: @Heisenbug I don't have Unity pro.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I get a bunch of errors in my event logs when I run the game. I added the event log errors to my original post.

Comment: Those errors seem to be about corrupted backup files.  Are there any log errors related to your game?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft Ahh yes I found it, i've pasted it in my question.